# Missed flight, can we take the airline to court to claim money to rebook remaining flights?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, civil-law

A couple of weeks ago me and my partner went on holiday. We had booked with Thai Airways and had a multi-part ticket. London -> Bangkok, Bangkok -> Tokyo, Osaka -> London (via Bangkok)
On the day of the Bangkok to Tokyo flight (Nov 17th), I had food poisoning, we got to the airport, but I was constantly throwing up and severely dehydrated, so we saw the airport doctor, they ruled me not fit to fly and sent me to the hospital in an ambulance, my partner stayed with me the entire time.
Whilst at the airport doctor's, one of the nurses took our flight information and went up to inform Thai that we wouldn't be able to make the trip (this was about 4 hrs before the flight was due), unfortunately there wasn't anybody manning the check-in desk so they weren't able to notify them, however they said they would return later to let them know.

I sent an e-mail to Thai the following morning (Nov 18th) when I was no longer incapacitated checking whether the remaining flights were still valid. 
The morning after that (Nov 19th), I received a call from Thai at 9am at the hospital saying that unless we rebooked our tickets (with a new Bangkok to Tokyo flight) at a cost of £1000 each (the original ticket cost us ~£740 each) by 11am, all our remaining flights would be cancelled.
We believe the airport doctor notified Thai (in Thai's T&C it states if they are informed prior to the flight they won't cancel the remaining flights), though we don't have any physical evidence.

We could have booked a flight to Tokyo by ourselves for aprox £300 each on the day.

Would there be any room for us to take Thai Airways to court to reclaim the £2000 we had to pay?

Comment: How is it the airlines fault that you got food poisoning?  Why do you think it was the medical staff's job to contact the airline for you?

Comment: @Andy I didn't assume it was their job, my partner would have gone up to inform them had the airport doctors medical staff not told us they'd do it themselves.

Comment: I don't get your thinking here; do you really think the airline is going to take the word of some random person that calls them to try and change your tickets?

Comment: 1) It isn't "some random person", it's a member of airport staff based at the airline's main hub.
2) Informing them that the person in their care won't be able to make the flight isn't the same as changing the tickets.

Comment: And how exactly would the airline verify the person is how they say they are on the phone, and are authorized to talk about the passengers tickets without talking to the passengers? And it is changing the tickets, because the airline will then take the passengers off the manifest for the flight and probably give the seats to others on standby.  Basically what you're suggesting is a great way for a malicious person to screw up someone's travel.

Comment: @Andy Likewise how would they verify it's me on the phone? The staff had access to all the booking details as we had provided them when asked.

Comment: You gave them the number of the credit card you used to pay, your home address,  stuff you provided but isn't on the ticket?  They had your cell phone so they could verify the phone number was coming from the number tied to the booking?  Giving that much information would be very foolish. Ultimately though, it's your responsibility to call the airline, not theirs.

Comment: @Andy As it were, they had to take those details anyway in order to admit me to hospital.

Comment: That doesn't mean they are allowed to share them. In the US HIPPA forbids sharing of any patient data unless necessary for medical treatment. I'd think the UK has something similar. And again, nurses and doctors are not paid to fix your travel plans.  Why are you even continuing this? You accepted the answer that says you have no legal recourse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

*You* missed the flight. Thai is not responsible for your acts and omissions. As for the check in desk, they are often unmanned, however, Thai have  an email address and a telephone number that *is* manned 24/7. I am surprised that you couldn’t find *any* Thai airlines staff in all of Bangkok airport given that it is their home base.

This is precisely what travel insurance is for.

Assuming that the fee was correctly charged under the contract terms in the relevant circumstances you have no right to have it waived. Thai *might* waive it gratuitously if you ask but they don’t have to.

Comment: Just to add to this, but its the passengers obligation to inform the airline of any issues with travelling for any T&Cs mentioned to count, not the airport doctors, the hospital or anyone else - if the passenger did not ensure that the airline was informed, the airline is entirely in the clear here.

Comment: Re the comment about being surprised that the OP couldnt find any Thai Airlines staff at a home base - I was stuck in AMS a few years back after a snow storm, and KLM literally closed all the help desks at 11.45PM despite the queue having several thousand people in it.  After that point, you couldn't find a single KLM staff member that had any authority to do anything - everyone had to wait until the desks reopened at 6am.  It was a nightmare.

Comment: @Moo yes, well, I’m surprised but not flabbergasted.

Comment: @Moo From the visit to the doctor I was completely incapacitated and unable to communicate with Thai, I took the airport doctor's staff word that they would communicate on my behalf.

Comment: @Kharenis and your partner?  Its not the hospitals responsibility or the airport doctors responsibility - they may have failed you in this regard with the promises they gave you, but it's not their responsibility to arrange anything with the airline.  In answer to your question Dale is correct - no, you have no recourse against Thai Airlines in this situation.

Comment: @Moo As mentioned in another comment, she happily would have communicated with Thai had we not been told by the airport doctor's staff that they would do it. They took all our flight details down first thing and told us they would inform the airline so we presumed it was one of their duties.  Either way, we had travel insurance and have submitted everything to them so fingers crossed it all gets covered anyway.

Comment: @Kharenis contract law is about risk allocation and who pays the risk of contingencies. You bear the risk of illness and notification even for circumstances beyond your control.

Comment: @DaleM Interestingly there is an example of somebody taking an airline to court over ticket cancellation from no-shows. (See James Dove vs Iberia) He won on the basis that it was an unfair contract term.